# How to use header units

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, c++20

MSVC 2019, v16.8.1

I'm trying to start changing some existing code to use modules. My first attempt is to take an existing DLL, move all code into headers, except for one file which needs to be cpp so the compiler builds the dll (won't build with just headers).

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

[Practical C++20 Modules and the future of tooling around C++ Modules with Cameron DaCamara](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ow2zV0Udd9M&t=1089s)

My first try was changing one `#import` statement. Within the CPP file:

Changed:

`#include "Some/Header.hpp"`

To:

`import "Some/Header.hpp";`

I get this error:

> error C7612: could not find header unit for '...../Some/Header.hpp'

I've tried all versions of the path to `Some/Header.hpp`, including absolute path, but the compiler just gives that same error.

Is there another step in the setup to instruct the compiler where to find headers? This is a CMake based project.

---

P.S. This modules feature seems, currently, very buggy. As soon as I started to use the `import` keyword, the IDE started to crash.

---

EDIT:
NVM, this feature is **definetly not fully cooked**. Just tried changing another file to be modules, and it started to complain about some non-existing error. When I made a change to the code it was pointing to, just to experiment, I get this:

```
3>DevelopVision.ixx
3>..\..\..\Source\AppletGame\DevelopVision.ixx(323,1): fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.
3>(compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1584)
3> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
3>If possible please provide a repro here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com
3>Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
3> Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
3>INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe'
```

I'll give it a try in another year or so.

Comment: [Per MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-160): "*As of Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2, modules are not fully implemented in the Microsoft C++ compiler.*" And "*Legacy imports are not yet implemented in the Microsoft C++ compiler.*" And "*The `.ixx` extension is required for module interface files in Visual Studio.*"  That said, it is not enough to just change an `#include` into an `import`, the file being imported has to actually be written for use with `import`. Did you update the `.hpp` file to include an `export module` statement?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: What you quoted was for 16.2, I'm on 16.8 -- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/a-tour-of-cpp-modules-in-visual-studio/
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-v16-8/

Comment: According to [Microsoft Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/standard-c20-modules-support-with-msvc-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-8/), `If you want to build a header unit for a .h file, you need to change its item type to be “C/C++ compiler” as by default .h files are in “C/C++ header” group and are not passed to the compiler. “C/C++ compiler” files with .h extension are considered “header units” by default.` You could try to set `C/C++ compile` in `Properties of .hpp->Item type`.

Answer (score 3):

As of Visual Studio 2019 version 16.10 Preview 3 (released 11 May 2021), header units appear to work properly.

Microsoft has a useful guide: [Walkthrough: Build and import header units in Microsoft Visual C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-header-units?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Will give it a try in the future. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Although the MS docs Walkthough is excellent, when trying it out on my MFC project with BCG Controls, I got a lot of errors. I changed one .h to Header Unit and got these types of errors and warnings: `1>LogMsgKeys.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winbase.h(9531,5): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winbase.h(9531,5): warning C5105: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior
`